# Get unique Id for the current user

Tags: android

How can I get a unique Id for the current user who is using my application?

I don't want to retrieve the `device UDID` (for my users privacy concerns).

I saw once that in the latest API versions (4.0+) there is such method to generate a unique 
id for the current android user, but I cannot find it now.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the official statement from Google

http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

You should really read it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using some kind of backend, so maybe you can create an endpoint that return a unique token that you save in the shared preferences.

Comment: That will work - but only as long as the user never uninstalls/reinstalls the app and/or buys a new phone. However, combining this solution with DataBackup (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) might work.